# Transfer the Whatsapp Windows Phone Backup file to Iphone

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

Is there any way to transfer the backup file from windows phone to Iphone 5S.

Iphone whatsapp restore the data from icloud so is there any way to replace that file with the Windows phone whatsapp backup file or manually restore the iphone whatsapp from that backup.

**or a way to atleast open and view the threads**

Following is the structure of Windows phone whatsapp backup file i have saved.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Reading your WhatsApp chat history:

Go to http://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/ and upload your message file. Select **ZWAMESSAGE** and press execute.

---

### Restoring WhatsApp's chat history to iPhone

This method worked for me when migrating from WA for Android to WA for iPhone. **This may not work** with your WP backup of WA. If this should be the case, please leave a comment below.

Warning: Please create a separate backup of your iPhone before following the steps below.

Step by step instruction:

1. Make sure you have installed and **configured WhatsApp** on your iPhone.
2. **Send someone a message**. This will create the chat history file.
3. **Connect** your iPhone to a computer running **iTunes**.
4. **Create a local, unencrypted backup** of your iPhone.
5. Go to **iTunes**' **settings** and navigate to the tab "**Devices**"
6. Under "Device backups:" you should see your created backup. **Right click** on the backup entry and choose "**Show in Finder**" (or similar if you are running Windows).
7. Open the folder and navigate to "**1b**" (folder).
8. Find the file "1b6b187a1b60b9ae8b720c79e2c67f472bab09c0" and delete it.
9. **Copy** your **Windows Phone's WhatsApp chat history** file to the "1b" folder and **rename** it to "1b6b187a1b60b9ae8b720c79e2c67f472bab09c0".
10. In iTunes, navigate to your iPhone and select **Restore**. Select the just created backup and follow the instructions.

This process will import your old chat history into WA on the iPhone. You may need to re-register your phone number with WA.

Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I’m trying to follow your intructions to transfer WhatsApp backup from my Windows phone to iPhone. I’ve been able to create the unencrypted local backup through iTunes on my desktop. But in the “1b” folder, there’s no file named “1b6b187a1b60b9ae8b720c79e2c67f472bab09c0”. There are three files that are named differently though.

Comment: no, its not working for me... i have iphone 6s and ios 11... i renamed one file in folder 1b (its almost similar to your), but itunes says that backup is corrupted (or something like that)...

Comment: @oa- this does not work anymore. The WhatsApp database file is encrypted on OneDrive.