# Transfer WhatsApp chat history from Windows Phone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, backup, data-transfer, file-transfer, whatsapp.app

[image: 1b folder of iPhone backup]I was trying to restore WhatsApp chat history by method described by ["oa-" user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/201668/oa) here on the forum. But can not ask him directly [Transfer the WhatsApp Windows Phone Backup file to  Iphone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237750/transfer-the-whatsapp-windows-phone-backup-file-to-iphone)

The **"1b6b187a1b60b9ae8b720c79e2c67f472bab09c0"** file (check the link above) does not exist in the "1b" folder of my iPhone backup. So, how can I tell which file in the "1b" folder is related to WhatsApp Chat Backup to replace it with file from my old Windows Phone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @oa Can you help out here?